# How to allow only admin-ajax.php to be crawled?

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt, crawl-errors

My robots.txt looks as follows:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

Google Webmaster Tool recently raised a warning saying:

```
Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt
```

I guess the **Disallow** at the folder level is overwriting the file level **Allow**. What is the way to get around this?

Comment: I don’t think so. Google recognized it was blocked, but proceeded anyway. That’s a giant WTF!

Comment: Google can index pages based on links to them rather than by crawling them.  Just because Google indexed the URL, it doesn't mean that it processed it by crawling it.

Comment: Have you tried using [Google's robots.txt testing tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598)?

Comment: Hi @StephenOstermiller .. i have and the tool highlights the Disallow line stating that /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php cannot be accessed by GoogleBot

Comment: Have you tried reordering the directives?   I thought that googlbot used a longest matching line heuristic but maybe order matters.  Or maybe they stopped supporting the nonstandard allow rules.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, tried changing the order, still throws the error. Order doesn't seem to matter :(

Comment: @StephenOstermiller oops sorry, my sitemap instruction was in between. The order matters! The testing tool passes it! Thanks a ton. Perhaps you can add that as an answer? will be handy for others who are stuck with this.

Comment: The sitemap directive would start a new section.   Typically, those go at the top.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you indicate that the problem was caused by a sitemap directive you didn't include in the original question.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. The order of Allow and Disallow matters in the Robots.txt file. I had Disallow first and then Allow with Sitemaps on the same line as Allow. When I cut paste the Allow line, it went with the Sitemaps statement by mistake. In short.. The default robots.txt gets created with Disallow first and then Allow. If that order is changed to Allow first and then Disallow .. Then the Allow is honoured. So Order does matter. And your guess was correct.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, updates: after submitting the edited robots.txt, with the changed order of allow and disallow, google came back saying the error is not cleared. Thanks much. I also noticed that this error caused the site to be penalized to incur a drop of 35% traffic. Thanks a ton!